# how to rename objects in AWS s3 in c#

Tags: c#, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3

I'm using AmazonS3Client in c# and I can't see any method to rename an object any idea how to do that?

```
private AmazonS3Client _client;

    public AWSBucketRepository(AmazonS3Client client)
    {
        _client = client;
    }

    public string RenameObject(string objectPath , string newObjectName)
    {
        
    }
```

Comment: Copy it and delete the old one, S3 does not have a renaming feature.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As explained in the [docs](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/sdk-for-java/v1/developer-guide/examples-s3-objects.html#copy-object), you can copy object to itself with new name:

> You can use copyObject with deleteObject to move or **rename an object**, by first copying the object to a new name (you can use the same bucket as both the source and destination) and then deleting the object from its old location.